# Is there a way to receive a picture from a node-red server in a node.js server?

Tags: node.js, upload, node-red

I have a picture in my node-red server and i would like to send and save it to my Node.js server.

In node-red I read the picture and put it on a buffer and then send it to my node.js server at /upload-picture. In node.js I recover the picture in the body's request and write it in a file using "fs.writeFile".

```
router.post('/upload-picture', async (req, res) => {
    //TODO : Secure with a common token with Node-RED
    //       Maybe check the incoming IP
    //       Get the author in the request body and store the picture in the right directory
    fs.writeFile(__dirname + "\\..\\users_pictures\\" + req.body.author_email + "\\" + req.body.image_name, req.body.image_content, function(err){
        if (err) {
            console.log("Cannot create this file.");
            return res.status(400).send('{"error":"Cannot create this file."}');
        }
        console.log("Receive picture from Node-RED.");
    });
    return res.status(200).send('{"status":"ok"}');
});
```

The Node-RED flow read a picture and send it on the payload to Node.js thanks to a HTTP request node.

The Node-RED flow :

```
[{"id":"d1eb8bbe.aa09b8","type":"tab","label":"Flow 5","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"6010b409.a3b3bc","type":"inject","z":"d1eb8bbe.aa09b8","name":"Upload picture to Node.js","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":170,"y":180,"wires":[["d1bc2c3f.88046"]]},{"id":"4ec67dff.2b6ed4","type":"http request","z":"d1eb8bbe.aa09b8","name":"","method":"POST","ret":"txt","paytoqs":false,"url":"http://localhost:4000/node-red-com/upload-picture","tls":"","proxy":"","authType":"basic","x":1050,"y":180,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"8324a4e.c0f7358","type":"file in","z":"d1eb8bbe.aa09b8","name":"","filename":"C:\\Users\\Natasha\\Desktop\\image.png","format":"utf8","chunk":false,"sendError":false,"encoding":"none","x":650,"y":180,"wires":[["c622e101.e7c8b"]]},{"id":"c622e101.e7c8b","type":"function","z":"d1eb8bbe.aa09b8","name":"","func":"var tmp = msg.payload;\nmsg.payload = {};\nmsg.payload.image_name = 'test.png';\nmsg.payload.author_email = 'admin@admin.fr';\nmsg.payload.image_content = tmp;\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":890,"y":180,"wires":[["4ec67dff.2b6ed4"]]},{"id":"d1bc2c3f.88046","type":"function","z":"d1eb8bbe.aa09b8","name":"","func":"msg.payload = {};\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":410,"y":180,"wires":[["8324a4e.c0f7358"]]}]
```

The file is created but I can't open it. When I  run the command "file my_picture.png". The output is "my_picture.ong: data"

Comment: You need to edit the question to show us what you have done at the Node-RED end. Currently your description is not detailed enough.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have added my flow from Node-RED

Answer (score 0):

The flow you posted shows that you are very close to the solution.

Let´s review the help information given by the http-request node:

```
File Upload
To perform a file upload, msg.headers["content-type"] should be set to multipart/form-data and the msg.payload passed to the node must be an object with the following structure:

{
    "KEY": {
        "value": FILE_CONTENTS,
        "options": {
            "filename": "FILENAME"
        }
    }
}
The values of KEY, FILE_CONTENTS and FILENAME should be set to the appropriate values.
```

So it is missing that you create the appropriate headers.

The following flow should work ok for you:

```
[{"id":"4740a2f1.624d8c","type":"tab","label":"Flow 5","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"272eb30e.f1d66c","type":"http request","z":"4740a2f1.624d8c","name":"","method":"POST","ret":"txt","paytoqs":false,"url":"http://localhost:4000/node-red-com/upload-picture","tls":"","proxy":"","authType":"basic","x":810,"y":140,"wires":[["da0ef8a9.5aeb88"]]},{"id":"da0ef8a9.5aeb88","type":"debug","z":"4740a2f1.624d8c","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":1010,"y":140,"wires":[]},{"id":"29b4d5aa.000c7a","type":"inject","z":"4740a2f1.624d8c","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":120,"y":140,"wires":[["dc21a65f.5bc368"]]},{"id":"dc21a65f.5bc368","type":"file in","z":"4740a2f1.624d8c","name":"","filename":"C:\\Users\\Natasha\\Desktop\\image.png","format":"","chunk":false,"sendError":false,"encoding":"none","x":350,"y":140,"wires":[["778e6d04.bf39a4"]]},{"id":"778e6d04.bf39a4","type":"function","z":"4740a2f1.624d8c","name":"Set header","func":"msg.payload = {\n    \"KEY\": {\n        \"value\": msg.payload,\n        \"options\": {\n            \"filename\": \"C:/Users/Natasha/Desktop/image.png\"\n        }\n    }\n}\n\nmsg.headers = {};\nmsg.headers[\"Content-Type\"] = \"multipart/form-data\";\n\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":630,"y":140,"wires":[["272eb30e.f1d66c"]]}]
```